# Android. Вызов стандартного редактора фото без Chooser app

Tags: android-studio

Хочу при startActivity(editIntent) переходит сразу в стандартный редактор фото.
 А так появляется окно с выбором приложений для редактирования, которые не возвращают data как стандартный и они не подходят.

Мой код:

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                editIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                editIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(editIntent);
```

Может какой флаг добавить?

Answer (score 0):

Одним флагом не обойтись. Идея состоит в том, что вы должны через менеджер пакетов найти нужно приложение и запустить его.

Данный пример ищет `gmail`:

```
final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfoatches> = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
ResolveInfo best = null;
for (final ResolveInfo info : matches){
  if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(“.gm”) ||
      info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(“gmail”)){
    best = info;
  }
}

if (best != null){
  intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
}

ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

uris.add(Uri.parse(“file:”+file_path + file1Name));
uris.add(Uri.parse(“file:”+file_path + file2Name));
uris.add(Uri.parse(“file:”+file_path + file3Name));

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, context.getString(R.string.MY_OVERTIME_SUMMARY_BODY));
if(best == null) {
  context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
} else {
  context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

[Источник](https://asishinwp.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/send-mail-directly-skip-chooser/)